# Show calendar on custom DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, custom-datetimepicker

I created a custom **datetimepicker** based on the `UserControl` in Visual Studio 2010 c#. There are a `RichTextBox`, a `Button` and `MonthCalendar` in this control.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT8Lw.png.

I change height of the UserControl to hide/show calendar. My problem is that when I place this control on the `GroupBox` which is located on the **panel**, parent overlaps it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQMuo.png

I've solved this looping back on controls **Parent** until the main form is found and then setting it as parent of my DateTimePicker.

```
    Control parent = this.Parent ?? null;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            if (parent is Form)
                break;
            parent = parent.Parent;

        }
        this.clnMonth.Parent = parent;
        clnMonth.Location = this.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
```

I've tried to place `MonthCalendar` on another form and show/hide it after click, but there where huge problem positioning the form under the **DateTimePicker**. The above method works fine, but I know it's not the best solution. Could you give me any alternative idea?

Comment: I think the problem is that you do multiple GUI updates in one event. Some drawing is not performed as long as the message queue is halted.